# What is the need for a cookbook as opposed to having just a reference manual?

Tags: documentation

What suggestions would you make to write a cookbook to use a distributed database? Does having a tangible end goal enough to distinguish a cookbook from a reference document? What else should I consider when writing a technical cookbook?

I'm thinking - create a scenario that needs addressing and walk the reader through the exact steps needed to accomplish it.

Does the pivot to solving a pre-defined problem differentiate a cookbook from a reference manual which contains all the necessary information about the technology?

Comment: This isn't specifically about software engineering; cookbooks occur in other fields, too.

Comment: Example [reference document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket(v=vs.110).aspx).  Example [cookbook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w89fhyex(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cookbook usually discusses common themes and topics, often the ones that are most popular/requested amongst the users. It will skip some topics entirely (usually the ones seen as obscure/arcane), but may spend a lot of time coming up with different approaches to solve the same problem in different circumstances.

The reference manual will probably try to list everything (or almost everything) in an API/library, but the examples given (*IF* any are given) will probably be trivial, just enough to illustrate usage.

Example:

A cookbook for a web server might show you 5 different ways to configure your website to allow HTTPS (maybe for different platforms/environments, different security setups, etc...). The "recipe" might not go into every possible config option, just the most common ones for this task.

The reference manual will list all of the possible config options necessary to do this, but probably won't have a lot of detailed example handling different situations.

Answer (score 2):

They are rather different things.  A reference manual would simply document the interfaces to something.  A cookbook would contain examples of how to use the interfaces to achieve things.

Answer (score 1):

Some cookbooks focus on specific common set of problems and suggest a solution pattern. They are problem-oriented. A reference manual attempts to list all features. Reference manuals are mostly feature-oriented than problem-oriented. Anyway. All the above is based on my observation with IT books only.